# How to Read MP3

Tags: java, mp3

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938304/how-to-get-audio-data-from-a-mp3) I was able to find out how to read mp3 files, but I'm still confused as to how to actually use this.

```
File file = new File(filename);
AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioInputStream din = null;
AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 
                                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                                        16,
                                        baseFormat.getChannels(),
                                        baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                                        false);
din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
```

After these declarations, how do you use `din`? I know the loop would look something like this:

```
while (/*What do I put here??*/){
    int currentByte = din.read();
}
```

In other words, I'm just asking how to read the entire array of bytes from the mp3 file, inspecting them one at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioInputStream.read() [returns -1 when it's out of data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#read()), so you can break your loop when that happens:

```
while (true){
    int currentByte = din.read();
    if (currentByte == -1) break;
    // Handling code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/Array.txt");
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);

    byte b[] = new byte[10];
    din.read(b);
    din.close();
  }
```

provided by:http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/ReadbytearrayfromfileusingDataInputStream.htm